# Mercurial 'hg commit --logfile' working from commandline but not Python

Tags: python, mercurial

I'm auto-generating 'hg add' then 'hg commit' commands and executing from Python 3.8 on Win 10.

The automation writes the commit template out to a temp file then passes it to the hg commit command using the --logfile / -l parameter.  If I run from the commandline 'hg commit' works fine and uses the template stored in the temp file:

```
hg commit -l path/to/my/GeneratedCommitTemplate
```

However if I attempt to run 'hg commit' using Python, hg seemingly ignores the -l param and pops up notepad with a generic commit template:

```
subprocess.run(["hg", "commit", "-l", "path/to/my/GeneratedCommitTemplate"], cwd=repoBasePath, check=True)
```

I'm executing 'hg add' from Python the same way and that works fine.

What could cause 'hg commit' to not detect the -l param or the template file when executed from Python?